# System assemblies not found for .Net v3.5 when starting new project or trying to open existing one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, .net-3.5

when I'm trying to open existing project that targets .Net 3.5 or create a new one that targets it, Visual Studio can't find some .Net Framework assemblies:
[image]

As you can see, `System`, `System.Data`, `System.Drawing`, `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.Xml` are not found.

The errors that I'm getting upon build look something like

```
Warning MSB3267 The primary reference "System", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". 
To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System".
```

If I retarget the project to something like .Net v4.5 then all assemblies are found but I need it to build with v3.5 as a target.

What I've tried to fix the issue:
1) I made sure that .Net3.5 is enabled in Windows Features:
[image]

2) I made sure 3.5 dev tools are installed in Visual Studio:
[image]

3) I've tried to manually install .Net v3.5 from the [microsoft installation file](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/0/3/703455ee-a747-4cc8-bd3e-98a615c3aedb/dotNetFx35setup.exe)

None of these steps helped so far. I've tried to search for these missing dlls manually and found them in various subfolders of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`, mostly in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`.

What's the correct way to fix this? How do I point VS to the assemblies? Is there something wrong with my setup?

Software versions:
Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.53, Windows 10 Pro with some fresh updates

Comment: Maybe you can try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around, I've been told that it's an old and known bug in msbuild that has quite a few possible workarounds: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1333

I personally went with a custom `FrameworkPathOverride`: https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/1333#issuecomment-296346352, e.d. I've added this XML snipped to my `.csproj` that worked like a charm:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net35'">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Client</FrameworkPathOverride>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After that, unload/load project and I was good to go.